# Show that the series $\sum_{n,m=1}^\infty 1/(n+m)!$ is absolutely convergent and find its sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, factorial

Show that the series $$\sum_{n,m=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(n+m)!}$$  is absolutely convergent and find its sum.

This comes from a chapter called interchange of limit operations. I tried using the ratio test but wasn't sure if this was the correct route.

Comment: It's close to impossible to be sure what you meant to write. Use LaTeX for mathematics in this site.

Comment: You really need to learn to use TeX!

Answer (score 3):

While this doesn't address the issue of absolute convergence, it's easy to find the sum's value once you've justified the operations.  Consider introducing an auxiliary variable $k$ for $m+n$, and rewrite the double-infinite sum as a sum of 'diagonal sums' : $$\sum_{m,n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(m+n)!}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\left(\sum_{m+n=k}\frac{1}{(m+n)!}\right)
= \sum_{k=2}^\infty\left(\sum_{m+n=k}\frac{1}{k!}\right) =\sum_{k=2}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k!}\left(\sum_{m+n=k}1\right)\right)$$

Now, the value of the inner sum should be easy to find; then use that to simplify the expression.  You should find a familiar value for the outer sum...

Answer (score 1):

Notice that:
$$\sum_{m,n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(m+n)!}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\sum_{\array{m+n=k\\m,n\geq 1}}\frac{1}{k!} = \sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{k-1}{k!}\leq\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{k(k-1)}{k!}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(k-2)!}<\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle{\large%
{\cal Q}\left(z\right)
\equiv
\sum_{n, m = 1}^{\infty}{z^{m + n} \over \left(m + n\right)!}\,,
\qquad
{\cal Q}\left(1\right)\ =\ ?}$

\begin{align}
{\cal Q}'\left(z\right)
&=
\sum_{n, m = 1}^{\infty}{z^{m + n - 1} \over \left(m + n - 1\right)!}
=
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}{z^{m + n} \over \left(m + n\right)!}
=
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[%
{z^{n} \over n!}
+
\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}{z^{m + n} \over \left(m + n\right)!}
\right]
\\[3mm]&=
{\rm e}^{z} - 1 + {\cal Q}\left(z\right)
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
{{\rm d}\left[{\rm e}^{-z}\,{\cal Q}\left(z\right)\right] \over {\rm d}z}
=
1 - {\rm e}^{-z}\,,\quad {\cal Q}\left(0\right) = 0
\\[1mm]-&-----------------------------
\end{align}

$$
{\rm e}^{-z}\,{\cal Q}\left(z\right) - {\rm e}^{-0}\,{\cal Q}\left(0\right)
=
\left(z + {\rm e}^{-z}\right) - \left(0 + {\rm e}^{-0}\right)
=
z + {\rm e}^{-z} - 1
$$

$$
{\cal Q}\left(z\right)
=
z\,{\rm e}^{z} + 1 - {\rm e}^{-z}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
{\cal Q}\left(1\right) = {\rm e} + 1 - {\rm e}^{-1}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\
\color{#ff0000}{\large\quad%
\sum_{n, m = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \left(m + n\right)!}
\color{#000000}{\ =\ }
{\rm e} + 1 - {\rm e}^{-1}
\quad}
\\ \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the top right quadrant of a graph with axes of $m$ and $n$. With each integer point not on the axes, give it a value of $\frac{1}{(m+n)!}$. Now draw rings around points with the same value, and we realise the original sum is equal to $\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{r}{(r+1)!}$. Define $S_n=\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r}{(r+1)!}$ and calculating the first few $S_n$, we can conjecture that: $S_n=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$, which is very easy to prove by induction. Letting $n$ tend to infinity we obtain the original sum, which is equal to 1.